# Use jQuery to update database using POST method

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send every data from the form to an external php file and update the database values. It seems nothing happens. Console doesn't show any errors. I have searched for responses and nothing seems to work for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#updatesettings').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var lang = $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').text();
        console.log('lang=' + lang +'&'+ $(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "modules/game/updatesettings.php",
         data: 'lang='+lang+'&'+$(this).serialize(),
        }).done(function(data){
          console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
;
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="updatesettings" method="post">
          <p>
              <label for="link">LINK</label>
              <input type="text" name="link" class="textbox" id="link" value="<?php echo $tlink;?>" placeholder="LINK"> <?php if($tlink != "") echo'<i class="fa fa-check green"></i>'; else echo'<i class="fa fa-times red"></i>';?>
            </p>
          <p>
              <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" class="textbox" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="E-MAIL"><?php if($email != "") echo' <i class="fa fa-check green"></i>'; else echo' <i class="fa fa-times red"></i>';?>
            </p>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $langset; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="flag flag-usa flag-1x"></span> English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="flag flag-rou flag-1x"></span> Romana</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <p><input type="submit" class="button" href="#" value="Save settings"></p>
        </form>
```

The external php file that I try to use for update is this.

```html
<?php
@include_once('modules/connections/dbconn.php');
$link = $_POST["link"];
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($link);
$email = $_POST["email"];
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$lang = $_POST["lang"]
if($lang=="English"){
 $lang="en";
}
else {
 $lang="ro";
}
mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'],"UPDATE users SET `link`='$link' WHERE `id`='$id'");
mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'],"UPDATE users SET `email`='$email' WHERE `id`='$id'");
mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'],"UPDATE users SET `lang`='$lang' WHERE `id`='$id'");
exit;
?>
```

Thank you so much for trying to offer your help!

Comment: does request has been send? check it in network tab of debug console

Comment: Check the output of `'lang=' + lang + $(this).serialize()`. You're missing a `&` to join the values.

Comment: @bxN5 yes it is sending the request

Comment: @Daniel all post data is send? what is in the response? if response just empty you need debug your php code, call mysqli_error if your data in db does not updates

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no value shows in console if I try to print them

Comment: Really? Not even if you do `console.log('lang=' + lang + $(this).serialize())`?

Comment: @bxN5 It throws an error that there is no index.php file in that folder, but I don't try to call any file. Only in case if the session is not set.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Data sent through $(this) is working perfect. The lang variable is the problem. Nothing gets assigned to it.

Comment: I'm not sure how, as you can see from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j76fpekt/) what I mean. Your querystring is malformed. The issue with the lang setting is because the DOM traversal is incorrect. See my answer below for more detail

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan fixed that now, and now the errors come from the external php file. It says that every variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the result in case of success(done) or error(fail). Try:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updatesettings.php",
                  data: 'lang='+lang+'&'+$(this).serialize(),
        })
        .done(function(data){
          console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
```

**done()** is called when your request is correct, **fail()** in case of some error.

Tip: press *f12* and go to *Network* tab to check your requests.

Check [this pen](http://codepen.io/feardarkness/pen/WpwRGJ)

Comment: This is not enough. The main problem is with the data because nothing gets assigned to variable lang.

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly the querystring you're building is malformed. You need to add a `&` between the `lang` value and the rest of the serialised form data.  Secondly the DOM traversal to get the `.dropdown-toggle` text is incorrect. `this` will refer to the `form` element so you need to use `find()` to work down the DOM, not `parents()` to go up it.

It would also be worth adding a `success` and `error` handler, at least to aid debugging. Try this:

```
$('#updatesettings').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var lang = $(this).find('.btn-group .dropdown-toggle').text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updatesettings.php",
    data: 'lang=' + lang + '&' + $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {
      console.log('it worked!');
    },
    error: function(x, s, e) {
      console.log('it failed');
      console.log(x, s, e);
    }
  });
});
```